# How to use an inner join when using NOT Keyword

Tags: sql, join

The problem is to get "**Students who have not yet given exams**". In sql terms records where `ims_admission.exam_status` **IS NOT** `Active`.

I have three tables. **ims_admission,ims_batch,ims_course** respectively.

I have stored a **batch_id,course_id in every student's record**. These **id's** are the **primary key** of the respective tables.
Using these id's i want to **extract batch_name from ims_batch and course_name from ims_course table**
and where clause is where NOT ims_admission.exam_status ='Active'

I studied a little about joins. Made a query but i couldn't get results when using where clause. Except where clause i am getting records

**This is my query**

```
SELECT ims_admission.enq_applicant,ims_admission.batch_id,ims_admission.enq_course,ims_batch.batch_name 
FROM ims_admission 
INNER JOIN ims_batch ON ims_admission.batch_id = ims_batch.batch_id 
WHERE NOT ims_admission.exam_status = 'Active'
```

I want to get names of batch,course, where NOT exam_status ="Active"

Comment: Hint:  `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can do this with a `LEFT JOIN`, I think it is more natural to approach it using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT ia.*
FROM ims_admission ia
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM ims_batch ib
                  WHERE ib.batch_id = ia.batch_id AND
                        ib.exam_status = 'Active'
                 );
```

Comment: This is my new sql query. I made a temporary solution. I just changed the column to accept null values. And now i am able to get students whose exam status is NULL i.e. not active. 
`SELECT ims_admission.enq_applicant,ims_admission.exam_month,ims_batch.batch_name,ims_course.title FROM ims_admission INNER JOIN ims_batch ON ims_admission.batch_id = ims_batch.batch_id INNER JOIN ims_course ON ims_admission.enq_course = ims_course.course_id WHERE ims_admission.exam_status IS NULL`
Can you tell me if this will create any problem for me in the future?